# Is Reading Windows Reserved Filenames Through a URL Valid for OS Enumeration?

Tags: windows, exploit, audit, fuzzing, enumeration

I'm aware that **writing** a file with a reserved name such as CON.txt or CON.mp3, aux.txt, lpt1.html, etc. is not allowed by Windows and can be leveraged for enumeration.

However, what about ***reading*** a file with a reserved name?

For example, in my current web application, most invalid file requests return a proper 404 status from the application. However, /con, /aux, etc. return a 500 status runtime error message like this (which looks a lot like the IIS format, and that server instance may be likely to run on Windows but that's not enough to say definitively that it is Windows):

[image: The 500 error from the app]

(originally posted on StackOverflow and moved to security.stackexchange.com)

UPDATE: This appears to happen on any site that uses a specific 3rd party platform, so I've narrowed it down a bit further. I can post more about it here once I have permission from the vendor.

Comment: Short answer is possibly, but I'm unable to recreate your results on an 2019 IIS server.  curl --head http://X.X.X.194/aux
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0.  Provide additional information on your configuration

Comment: @kenkulas thanks for investigating - so far I've enumerated this as a AWS machine (using AWS web services, Amazon Cloudfront and Elastic Load Balancer), and I assumed it was IIS based on the format of the error message in the screenshot. Unfortunately, since this is a pen test, I do not have first hand knowledge of the exact configuration/version info. My current hypothesis is that perhaps this is being written to a log somewhere on the back end and this error is getting surfaced because of the filename.

Comment: Update: removing any tracking or 3rd party stuff from the single request that goes through doesn't make a difference. Of course it could still be logging attempted URLs as files on the back end, but that seems extremely strange to me. Other types of 500 errors return me to a more typical page, like "theirErrorPage.html?aspxerrorpath=/aValidPartOfTheSite"

Comment: As a sanity check for comparison: even when requesting C:\con in the Windows file browser (not even on a server, just locally), it's just a normal not found error. I'm pretty certain this is attempting to write on a Windows OS somewhere/somehow, judging from this experiment in Windows.